# Windows Phone 8 maps uri scheme

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a windows phone app and want to show the maps app. I know about the uri scheme's ms-drive-to, ms-walk-to and the HERE equivalents, but I don't want navigation. I also don't want to rely on HERE maps, because someone might not have installed that one. The question:

Is there a way of opening the default Map app on windows phone 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`MapsTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206989%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) API;

```
MapsTask mapsTask = new MapsTask();

//Omit the Center property to use the user's current location.
//mapsTask.Center = new GeoCoordinate(47.6204, -122.3493);
mapsTask.ZoomLevel = 2;

mapsTask.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [sdk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681884).

If you really want to open the apps, you can do it with a trick. Add a brower task an follow steps of [this article](http://habaneroconsulting.com/Blog/Posts/Translating_schema_org_s_postalAddress_microdata_into_useful_links_for_mobile.aspx).